# Can a function exist that changes the argument of another, periodic function?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Can a function that takes a periodic function as an input essentially change the argument of that function?

I started to think about this when experimenting in a DAW (digital audio workspace). In it, there is a controller LFO (low frequency oscillator) generating a sine wave with values between $0$ and $1$ . That means it is the function $y=f(x)=0.5+0.5\sin(x)$. [This is what the controller looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJD5a.png)

The phase and frequency of the LFO can be changed in the settings of the controller. The output of this LFO can be linked to many other controls in the DAW, such as volume, panning, filters and many other effects, after being manipulated by some other function $g(f(x))$, where $f(x)$ here is the output of the LFO. [This is what the control's mapping looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JXLh.png)

I am wondering, if there are such functions $g(f(x))$, so that controls linked to the same $LFO$ could be phase shifted, or the frequency could be changed, such that $y=g(x)=0.5+0.5\sin(ax+b)$ or at least be made into $y=g(x)=0.5+0.5\cos(x)$. So, for example, when a sound is being oscillated from left to right, at the same time, the volume of the sound would oscillate at the same frequency, just phase shifted and/or frequency changed so it does not coincide with the panning. It can easily be done by adding separate LFOs but this is something to think about.